# JavaScript in HTML code: Random numbers are not evenly distributed

Tags: javascript, random

I've got the following problem:
I'm uploading a survey on amazon mturk using Python and the survey is done via HTML and javascript. I show one of three different versions of the survey to participants, which I select by generating a random number via javascript. I store the number in local storage to prevent refreshing the website from resetting it. The problem I find is that more people seem to get versions 1 than version 3. But I cannot recreate the problem for myself when running the code in Tryit Editor online.

Could you please help me understand (and fix) why this happens? The following is the (trimmed) HTML code that I upload. I replaced text and removed fluff.

```
<HTMLQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">
<HTMLContent><![CDATA[
<!-- YOUR HTML BEGINS -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>
<script>
function test(){
    document.getElementById('txt-field').value = "1";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'><input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId'/>
  <span>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="link_click" id='txt-field' value="0" style="display: none">    
<div><h3><a href="www.google.com" target="_blank" id='report420' onclick="test()" >link</a></h3>
Instructions</div>
<div><table border="1" style="height: 258px;" width="196"><tbody>Table</tbody></table></div>
</span>
<!--I think the relevant part starts here-->
<script> 

document.write("Miscellaneous question");

var i = localStorage.getItem('i') || Math.floor(3*Math.random());
localStorage.setItem('i',i);

if (i==0){
document.write("Version 1");
}
if (i==1){
document.write("Version 2");
}
if (i==2){
document.write("Version 3");
}
document.write("Miscellaneous question");

</script>
<p><input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Submit' /></p></form>
<script language='Javascript'>turkSetAssignmentID();</script>
</body></html>
<!-- YOUR HTML ENDS -->
]]>
</HTMLContent>
<FrameHeight>600</FrameHeight>
</HTMLQuestion>
```

Comment: Do you have stats for the number of clients getting each version ?

Comment: I have them for slightly different versions, but accumulated they are: version 1: n=156, version 2: n=138, version 3: n=106. With a Pearson's Chi-Square test (df=2), it's significant at 99% (Chi-square=9.62).

Comment: That's a really hard assumption, in small amounts randomness may seem deviant, if you throw a coin ten times and get 8 heads and only two tails, analyzing  this sampling alone, you will have the illusion of a unnatural randomness. On how many surveys are you basing your assumption?

Comment: Across different versions with the same layout of the randomization, I have n=400 now. A common statistical test suggests it's biased (Chi-square=9.62, p<0.01).

Comment: Are those stats the distributed versions count or the submitted versions count ?

Comment: They are of different versions, but the changes are in the design of the other parts of the survey - like what goes into the survey versions, etc. The randomization part had only two different versions: either the one you see or one where I don't save the variable in local storage, so the code for that would be replacing the two lines "var i = localStorage.getItem('i') || Math.floor(3*Math.random());
localStorage.setItem('i',i);" i=Math.floor(3*Math.random());

Comment: I only thing I use in the code itself is that you are using a pretty common name for your local storage variable, i. It is pretty easy to think of a scenario where someone else has already used this variable, so you might be trying to save a variable that already has a value, and there is no error checking for if i already exists as not a number or is greater than 3.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my previous comment too late. In the other version where I don't save the variable in local storage, I replace

var i = localStorage.getItem('i') || Math.floor(3*Math.random());
localStorage.setItem('i',i);

with 

var i=Math.floor(3*Math.random());

Comment: I changed the name of the variable to something more unique, thank you! It seems no one mentioned another possible issue, so I will go ahead and implement the survey.

Comment: @Mirko did this end up working for you? I have a very similar issue that I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The random function `Math.floor(3*Math.random())` has uniform distribution, but I don't think that 400 samples are enough so that you can see it in action (as @desoares mentioned).

Testing code:

```js
var count = [0, 0, 0];
var n = 1000000;
document.write('Testing for ' + n + ' samples : ');
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    count[Math.floor(3*Math.random())]++;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(count));
```

```js
var count = [0, 0, 0];
var n = 400;
document.write('Testing for ' + n + ' samples : ');
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    count[Math.floor(3*Math.random())]++;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(count));
```

Also, if you want to be sure that people from the same computer are not forced to take the same version, you should clear the saved variable `localStorage.removeItem('i');` on submit. You may also add an expiration mechanic.

Comment: I think that it depends on the result. Suppose you found there to be no occurrence of the third version - that would be quite indicative of a biased random generator or a mistake.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client on a browser, the browser should follow the specification of the javascript (you can't control that), based on that and the info you gave us, the code should produce a uniform distribution. But there is always a small possibility that we live on the parallel universe that your code will never select the 3rd version.